# Proof of $\int_a^b f(nx) \;dx=\frac{1}{n} \int_{na}^{nb} f(x) \;dx $

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be continuous. How to prove this ?
>   $$\int_a^b f(nx) \;dx=\frac{1}{n} \int_{na}^{nb} f(x) \;dx $$ where $n \in N$

Really I don't know where to start. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would substitute $$nx=t$$ then we get $$x=\frac{t}{n}$$ and $$dx=\frac{1}{n}dt$$
and $$t_1=na$$ and $$t_2=nb$$

Comment: Thanks!........

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Try the substitution $u=nx$.

Answer (score 0):

Set the indefinite integral of f(x) as F(x). Then the indefinite integral of f(nx) equals (1/n)F(nx). I think you can derive that theorem using the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Frankly I don’t know anything about math, so if I made mistakes please let me know!!